# BIT(1) HIbernate JPA mapping

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, types, hibernate-mapping

In Postgresql I have a column with type BIT(1). In JPA mapping it's like:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="bit(1)")
private String type;
```

But, when I perform tests, this error occurs:

*ERROR: column "type" is of type bit but expression is of type character varying
   Tip: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
   Rank: 117*

I've tried with other Java types: char, int, Boolean, and BitSet. But, the same error occurs.

Do you know how can I map Postgresql type BIT(1) to Hibernate JPA??

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html

Comment: ERROR: column "type" is of type bit but expression is of type boolean
   Tip: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
   Rank: 117

Comment: Is there any good reason to use bit(1) here? I suppose a simple boolean would be more straighforward.

Comment: It is a requirement for the project... I'm just developing the persistence layer.

Comment: Maybe, but i don't see any valid usecase for `bit(1)` - but i am happy to learn something new. IMHO it is just a waste of space (a bit(1) uses 6 bytes of storage).

Comment: In Postgres you should be using `boolean` rather than `bit(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate doesn't support type bit of PostgreSQL. 
Try to use the native query of spring JPA with the cast. For example:

```
@Modifying  @Query(value = "update table set is_active = cast(:is_activeas bit) where id = :id", nativeQuery = true)

int updateTable(@Param("is_active") int isActive, @Param("id") long id);
```